# Xamarin Forms Picker - Crash on "ItemsChange"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, picker, xamarin.forms

I'm building with Xamarin Forms a Content Page. This content page has a Title and a Picker. Everytime the user select an item from the Picker (like answering an answer) his answer is stored, the Title change and the Picker Items too.

The problem is that very Often I got an "array out of index" exception that I cannot understand. My code is like this:

```
public FormContentPage ()
    {
       //create picker
       //create title
       Init(CurrentQuestion);
    }

 public void Init(Question)
 {
       pick.SelectedIndexChanged -= Next;

        pick.SelectedIndex = -1;
        pick.Items.Clear ();

        foreach (var c in current.Choices)
            pick.Items.Add (c);

        pick.SelectedIndexChanged += Next;
 }

 void Next()
 {
        ContentSave();

        if (ValidateField(FormData.Current))
            Init(NextQuestion);
 }
```

The array out of index exception happens during the Add or during the Clear, it depends on something I'm not really understanding.

In the inner I can see the Picker Selected Item is still the old one, even if I force the Selected Item to be -1..

Does anybody have any hint for me?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean `force the Selected INDEX to be -1`?

Comment: I just want to call the Items.Clear() without crash. But in the exception I see something like the previous index and the exception is an IndexOutOfBound